# How do I reload a table without deleting existing views?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that spans across many tables by date.

```
table_name_YYYY_MM_DD
```

There are many VIEWS created across these date range tables. However whenever I need to reload a table, I have to delete all these views to remove dependency constraints

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name_YYYY_MM_DD cascade;
```

Is there a way to reload the table, as part of a transaction, to where the VIEWS don't need to be deleted. Eg create a new table, and swap their names, so that the transaction would guarantee the views don't need to be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't drop the table.  Instead, truncate it:

```
 truncate table table_name_YYYY_MM_DD
```

This removes all rows (quickly), but the table remains.  So other dependencies are not affected.

Afterwards, you need to insert the data back into the table, rather than recreating the table.